# python 3 datetime difference in microseconds giving wrong answer for a long operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, binary-search-tree, python-datetime

I'm doing a delete operation of 3000 elements from a binary search tree of size 6000 ( sorted therefore one sided tree). I need to calculate the time taken for completing all the deletes

I did this

```py
    bst2 = foo.BinarySearchTree() #init
    insert_all_to_tree(bst2,insert_lines) #insert 6000 elements
    start = datetime.now() #start time
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
      bst2.delete(line)  #deleting
      if (idx%10 == 0):
        print("deleted ", (idx+1), "th element - ", line)
    end = datetime.now()  #completion time
    duration = end - start 
    print(duration.microseconds) #duration in microseconds
```

I got the answer **761716** microseconds which is less than even a minute when my actual code ran for about **5 hours**. I expected something in the ranges of **10^9 - 10^10**. I even checked the max integer allowed in python to see if it's related to that but apparently that's not the problem.

Why I'm I getting a wrong answer for the duration?

Comment: The `microseconds` field can never exceed a million, because that's all the microseconds there are in a second.  It is not the *total* time, it's just the part of the time that's less than a second.

Comment: @jasonharper oh! i thought i get the difference in microseconds. my bad

Comment: @jasonharper would you mind giving it as an answer. this was where i went wrong. now i know how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

`datetime.now()` returns a `datetime`, so doing math with it doesn't work out. You want to either use `time.time()` (Python < v3.3), `time.perf_counter()` (Python v3.3 until v3.7) or `time.perf_counter_ns()` (Python > v3.7).

`time.time()` and `time.perf_counter()` both return `float`, and `time.perf_counter_ns()` returns `int`.

Comment: but after doing difference `end - start` i got an object with a `microseconds` field. sorry im coming from javascript land so dont mind the keywords i use

Comment: Yes.  It has a `microseconds` field, and `seconds`.  You'd need to look at both of them.  `63.192` seconds will be recorded as `seconds=63`, `microseconds=192000`.